# regex mixing with strings and patterns in awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I need to look up some text that I have tagged through AWK. The text will be in the following format:

Discipline1, Discipline2 etc. There are hundreds of these tags and I don't want to type in hundreds of copies back into awk. I would like this to work but it won't and I have never had luck mixing strings and variables together in awk:

```
awk -v num="$i" '/Area(no space here)num\y/{print $0}'
```

Please help :)

Comment: Show your sample input and expected output.

Comment: Here is some text that has been tagged in regards to Area1 and I want to extract.

Comment: awk -v num="$i" '/Area(no space here)num\y/{print $0}'           which should lead to : Area1 being extracted.

Comment: Do you want to match arbitrary text followed by a number?

Comment: It's not arbitrary, but repeated throughout the document. I had to tag it to make an anchor for awk to remove a section of text. Ultimately I want the following: awk '/Discpline Area1/,  /LSSC/   ; where Area1 is represented by Area & i++ . In other words there are many AreasN which N=(1-300)

Comment: Please create a simplified input and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Your overall goal is not very clear, so here I'll answer the question that might help for the task at hand.

Let's assume we have a file `area` with contents

```
Area1
Area2
Area3
Area4
Area5
Area6
Area7
Area8
Area9
Area10
Area11
Area12
Area13
Area14
Area15
Area16
Area17
Area18
Area19
```

you want to search for each entry separately.  For example for `i=1` you don't want to have entries Area11..Area19.  Then, don't use pattern matching, but instead use equality.

```
awk -v num="1" '$0=="Area"num' area
```

will return single match

```
Area1
```

as expected.

Comment: I have 300+ matching lines over 10,000 pages. I am not inclined to type 300 versions of awk when I know I can do something akin to : num="$A", passing the value of A into awk as it increments. re-usability is key. Perhaps it would be helpful to say I am looking for something akin to num="$A"++, if it actually existed.  I'm just going to default to an array and push each element (in this case a number) into a variable defined within awk.

Comment: I omitted that since it's trivial. You can easy change it to ` i=1; awk -v num="$i" '$0=="Area"num' area`  awk will still see the actual value thanks to quote expansion.  Or, more explicitly in the loop `for i in {1..10}; do awk -v num="$i" '$0=="Area"num' area; done`.  However I'm not clear what your overall goal is.

Comment: Well, not so trivial if you don't know. Other languages are more...explicit. I like what Bash can do but it isn't obvious unless you've had a lot of experience with it.